# Using @Embedded in a @MappedSuperclass throws a duplicate exception

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I was trying to add a **value object** in an abstract class marked with `@MappedSuperclass` but it complains about duplicated definitions...

```
...
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Animal
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="Noe\HasABundle\Entity\Embeddable\Address")
     */
    private $address;
    ...
```

Then extend it like

```
...
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Dog extends Animal
{
    ...
```

And running `app/console doctrine:mappin:info` I get the duplication error.

So then I implemented a naming strategy handler and it seems that Doctrine is mapping the embedded object directly to the abstract class because in `embeddedFieldToColumnName` the `$className` is **Animal**...

What I want is to have several entities, extending from **Animal** but having their own tables (just like `@MappedSuperclass` works).

Am I missing something here or is just a bug?

Embeddeding the address directly to each animal subclass works...

**Doctrine 2.4**

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-3027

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields from the MappedSuperclass embedded properties are getting mapped directly into the MappedSuperclass fields causing the error.

I've proposed a PR fixing this:

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/1023